# Are javascript functions closely related to the bootstrap used version?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I've created a function that segments each letter in the paragraph to create the typing effect. But,
after a few days off, I saw that the effect is the opposite, namely the letters disappear.
Long story short, I tried to animate the desired paragraph letter by letter in order to achieve the so-called writing effect.
The whole process was a success, but after I had to change the bootstrap version, the function behaves in antithesis. When starting the web page, the paragraph gradually disappears.
What can be the cause of the problem?
The code is attached bellow.
Thanks in advance!

```
   <pre>
    index.html
    </pre> 
        

      <div class="id">

              <h1 class="title">

                  Hot Beans Coffee Shop
              </h1> 

            <p class="subtitle">

                "Born out of unique appreciation for coffee"
                
            </p>

            <script src="./app.js"></script>
            
            
        </div>
    
    
  <pre>
       app.js
    </pre>
    
    
       const text= document.querySelector(".id.subtitle");

       const strText=text.textContent;

       const splitText= strText.split("");

       text.textContent = "";
    
       for ( let i=0 ; i<splitText.length; i++){

           text.innerHTML+="<span>" + splitText[i] + "</span>";
      }
    
        let char=0;

        let timer=setInterval(onTick, 50);
    
       function onTick(){

           const span=text.querySelectorAll("span")[char];

           span.classList.add("fade");

           char++;

            if(char === splitText.length){

            complete();

            return; 
           }
        }
    
        function complete(){

            clearInterval(timer);

             timer=null;
      }
    
    
   <pre>
       app.js
    </pre>
        
   

         
            span{

                opacity: 0;
 
                transition: all 0.3 s ease;
    
    
    
            } 

          span.fade{
        
             opacity: 1;
        
    
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's working fine with couple of changes.
Changing selector from **".id.subtitle"** to "**.id .subtitle"** and span opacity from **1** to **0**.

```js
const text = document.querySelector(".id .subtitle");
const strText = text.textContent;
const splitText = strText.split("");
text.textContent = "";

for (let i = 0; i < splitText.length; i++) {
  text.innerHTML += "<span class='typing-text'>" + splitText[i] + "</span>";
}

let char = 0;
let timer = setInterval(onTick, 50);
function onTick() {
  const span = text.querySelectorAll(".typing-text")[char];
  span.classList.add("custom-fade");
  char++;
  if (char === splitText.length) {
    complete();
    return;
  }
}

function complete() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = null;
}
```

```css
span.typing-text{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3 s ease;
} 

span.typing-text.custom-fade{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
 <div class="id">
      <h1 class="title">Hot Beans Coffee Shop</h1> 
      <p class="subtitle">"Born out of unique appreciation for coffee"</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: what version of cdn and src did u use ?

Comment: I've not used bootstrap, I just corrected mistakes in the snippets you posted. Any specific bootstrap version which is causing issues to you? May be it could be conflicting with class names you used "fade".

Comment: i'm using the latest version bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3

Comment: Yes it's issue with 'fade' class, renaming it to 'custom-fade' does worked. updated above snippets too.

http://jsfiddle.net/koraku/btsfpuao/1/

Comment: i tried so , but it doesn't work, that paragraph appears unchanged  when launching the web page. At least , now the paragraph it's visible but the animation i've created still doesn't work.Surprinsigly, i tried to copy/paste my code on jsfiddle.net and there it works perfectly . How is that possible ?

Comment: may be span has styles which are conflicting with other style(with different selectors with high specificity). I just updated above code snippets with specific class added to span element too. give it a try

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to understand what is conflicting with your code unless you provide replicating scenario with some code snippets.